# convert a list of x and y coordinates into multistring

Tags: list, python-2.7, multiline

I have a set of x and y coordinates as follows:

`x = (1,1,2,2,3,4)`
`y= (0,1,2,3,4,5)`

What is the best way of going about transforming this list into a multiline string format, e.g:

`x_y = [((1,0)(1,1)),((1,1)(2,2)),((2,2)(2,3)),((2,3)(3,4)),((3,4)(4,5))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pair up the elements of `x` and `y` with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> x = (1,1,2,2,3,4)
>>> y = (0,1,2,3,4,5)
>>> xy = zip(x, y)
>>> xy
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Then you can rearrange this into the kind of list in your example with a list comprehension:

```
>>> x_y = [(xy[i], xy[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(xy)-1)]
>>> x_y
[((1, 0), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (2, 2)), ((2, 2), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (3, 4)), ((3, 4), (4, 5))]
```

If you don't care about efficiency, the second part could also be written as:

```
>>> x_y = zip(xy, xy[1:])
```